# Flexbox item height independent of its content

Tags: css, flexbox

I know this sounds like again another question on flexbox which is solved elsewhere but I can't find a solution from google or stackoverflow existing posts.

The problem is simple.

*I have 3 children divs inside a parent div, one of them containing a content bigger than its final size. I would like each child to be `1/3` of its parent REGARDLESS of its content.*

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xeqo0msq/

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child red">
       <div class="content">1</div>
   </div>
   <div class="child blue">2</div>
   <div class="child green">3</div>
</div>
```

And the associated CSS:

```
.parent {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column; /*or row*/
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}

.child {
   flex: 1;
}

.content{
   width: 800px;
   height: 100px;
}

.red {background: red;}
.blue {background: blue;}
.green {background: green;}
```

For `flex-direction: row;` it works as expected: each child is `1/3` of its parent, although the first content is way bigger. The width acts as if it was independent from the content.

[image: Flex Row screenshot]

For `flex-direction: column;` the first child is way bigger than the two others.

[image: Flex Column screenshot]

Is it possible to achieve this using flexbox and `flex-direction: column;`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When defining as `flex-direction: row`, the width of parent is limited by the screen, so it is known. Flex distributes the widths to three children.

But when `flex-direction: column`, the parent height not known (determined by children). Although you define it as `height: 100%`, but this `100%` is relative to the height of its parent element, which is `body`. The height of `body` is not full-screen height.

There are three options for you:

1. Simply add a `height` value to `.child` will make their height controllable: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xeqo0msq/1/)
2. Limit the `.parent` height like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xeqo0msq/2/).
3. If what you want is `each child occupies 1/3 of the screen height`, you need to define the height of `html, body` to be `100%` like this demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xeqo0msq/3/)

Comment: The guy who downvoted me, could you please point out the reason? Maybe I miss something?